# PyQt - resize parent widget to its child

Tags: python, pyqt

Just a main widget with a tabs widget in it.

The problem is - when I run it, only part of tabs are shown (as shown on attached picture). So, you need to resize, or scroll tabs to get for the last.

[image]

How can I set it so that window shows all tabs from the start?

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # making tabs
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '111111')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '222222')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '333333')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '444444')

        # inserting in vbox
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(tabs)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

How can I get it resized for all tabs?
And where the problem is - is it parent widget, or tabs, or vbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `QTabWidget.setUsesScrollButtons(bool)`

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QWidget.__init__(self, parent)

        # making tabs
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        tabs.setUsesScrollButtons(False) #here is

        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '111111')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '222222')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '333333')
        tabs.addTab(QWidget(), '444444')
        # inserting in vbox
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self)
        vbox.addWidget(tabs)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
myapp = MainWindow()
myapp.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabwidget.html#usesScrollButtons-prop